# MongoDB search using multiple field in a Spring Boot project

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm working in a Spring project and I need to search using different fields for example: id, username, city, country, company, phonenumber ...
It's obvious that I don't need to write a method like:  studentRepository.findByIdAndUsernameAndCityAnd...
What I need exactly is the correspondent SQL query in MongoDB.

```
@Query("Select stu from Student stu 
         where (stu.entreprise.radical in ?6) 
           and (?1 is null or stu.status=?1) 
           and (?2 is null or stu.dateValidity=?2) 
           and (?3 is null or stu.montant=?3) 
           and (?4 is null or stu.devise=?4) 
           and (?5 is null or stu.referenceClient=?5) 
         order by stu.createdAt desc" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Should work like this:

```
db.collection.find({
  radical: {
    $in: [
      <value1>,
      <value2>,
      ...,
      <valueN>
    ]
  },
  $and: [
    {
      $or: [
        {
          status: null
        },
        {
          status: <value>
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      $or: [
        {
          validity: null
        },
        {
          validity: <value>
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      $or: [
        {
          montant: null
        },
        {
          montant: <value>
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      $or: [
        {
          devise: null
        },
        {
          devise: <value>
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      $or: [
        {
          referenceClient: null
        },
        {
          referenceClient: <value>
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{})
.sort({createdAt: -1})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thank you for your answer, but unfortunately i didn't get the idea. please to provide more explanation. Thank you!